# What does the schematic for a 5 to 1 multiplexer look like

Tags: digital-logic, schematics, multiplexer

I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of a 5-to-1 mux. How can you have 5 inputs if you use 2-input AND gates?

Comment: 5-to-1 muxs aren't very common. 4-to-1 or 8-to-1 are much more usual. Where did you read about a 5-to-1 mux?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but my assignment requires us to create verilog code for a 5-to-1 mux. I don't know what the code should look like so I was hoping someone could offer a schematic for it

Comment: Surely it would be an 8-to-1 with only 5 inputs presented to the outside world?

Comment: conceptually, neverminding library cells, (physical implementation.. which matters, don't get me wrong) i just draw a mux with 5 inputs and 3 control bits, the rest is just some RTL case statement that translates that.  maybe we should know more about how these "2-input AND gates" relate to gating the mux(?)  Do you feel like you don't have enough conditions/bits to satisfy selecting 5 inputs?  in Verilog RTL  `default`, in VHDL RTL `others` handles unused inputs, or was it as @transistor stated and you were not sure about unused inputs in-general?

Comment: I was just more confused on how the mux would work. I've only seen and used 2-to-1 muxes before and those are straightforward. So I guess I was just having trouble connecting the 5-to-1 mux design to the 2-to-1 design

Comment: If you want to use 2-to-1 muxes you takes three and make a 4-to-1. Then add one more 2-to-1 at the end and you have 5-to-1. In Verilog it is a 7-line case statement unless the assignment says you have to make it from 2-input AND gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 5-to-1 mux you must have (at least) 3 select inputs since 2 select inputs can only select from 4 data inputs. But with 3 select inputs there are 8 patterns, which is why you usualy have a 8-to-1 mux. But not every select pattern needs to have a unique choice. Consider a setup where select inputs 000-011 select data inputs A1-A4 and 100-111 always selects data input A5.

You can build such a 5-to-1 mux easily in two ways:

1) Take a 4-to-1 mux, connect A1-A4 and S0-S1 to it. Take the output of the 4-to-1 mux and connect it to one input of a 2-to-1 mux. Connect A5 and S2 to the remaining pins. Now you have a 5-to-1 mux.

2) Take a 8-to-1 mux and connect the A5 input to A6-A8 too.

Both ways can be optimized to use fewer gates if you aren't using premade ICs. Or you can design a 5-to-1 mux from scratch. Write out the truth table, solve the Karnaugh diagrams and optimize the logic function and so on.